# How can I call a script with $ScriptPath in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

As known that dot-source can be used to call a script with its full path:`."D:\User\Shuai\MyScripts\logicTest2.ps1"`.    If I use `$ScriptPath = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path`, `$X = $ScriptPath + "\logicTest2.ps1"`,I can get the full path of the `logicTest2.ps1`. Now I want to call the script with `$X`. But I do not know how to do it. I thought that `."$X"`will do the work, but it did not.

Comment: *but it did not* — what does that means? Do you got any errors?

Comment: I used `."$X"` to call the `logicTest2.ps1`. It did not work. The error said it can not tell if $X is the function or script. Also asked me to check the path.

Comment: Assuming the path was correct did you put a space there `. "$X"`

Comment: @Matt `$ScriptPath = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path`
`$X = $ScriptPath + "\logicTest2.ps1"`
`. "$X"` This is the code. I put a space there, it has the same error.

Comment: @Matt Well, I don't know why, but it works after I restart my PC. LOL

Comment: Also... you may want to change your `$X =` line to `$X = Join-Path $ScriptPath -Child 'logicTest2.ps1'` as you can then add the `-Resolve` switch to make sure the file is there if you run into trouble later.

Comment: Which version of PowerShell?  On v3 and later, you can use `. $PSScriptRoot\logictest2.ps1`   Also, in the case of `. "$x"`, you don't need the quotes - `. $x` should work fine as long as $x contains the correct absolute or relative path.  Note that executing from current dir requires `. .\logicTest2.ps1`.

Answer (score 0):

On v3 and later, you can use `. $PSScriptRoot\logictest2.ps1`. Also, in the case of `. "$x"`, you don't need the quotes - `. $x` should work fine as long as $x contains the correct absolute or relative path. Note that executing from current dir requires specifying the current dir (.) like so `. .\logicTest2.ps1`.  That's two dots, one to dot source and another to tell PowerShell you want to execute from the current directory.